# Interpreting adjusted relationship between two variables when using splines

Tags: regression, logistic, nonlinear-regression, splines

Suppose I am interested in regressing the boolean outcome `y` onto two continuous variables `x1`, and `x2`. I might fit a logistic regression model, and then interpret the coefficient of `x1` and say that this estimate for the relationship of `x1` on `y` is "adjusted for" `x2`.

However, instead of simple logistic regression, I would like to use splines (i.e. I don't want to assume that the relationship of `x1,x2` is linear in the log odds of `y`). I'd still like to obtain the similar interpretation though. That is, I'd like to study the relationship between `x1` and `y`, while controlling for `x2`.

Here is my attempt, using the Iris dataset as a working example in R:

```
library(splines)
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
y <- as.numeric(iris$Species == 'setosa')
df <- data.frame(y=y, x1 = iris$Sepal.Width, x2 = iris$Petal.Length)

fit <- glm ( y ~  ns(x1,3) + ns(x2,3), df,family=binomial)
basis.vectors <- ns(df$x1,3)
projection <- basis.vectors %*% coef(fit)[2:4]
(g <- qplot(x = df$x1, projection) + geom_point())
```

[image]

In particular, it is different from the relationship between $x1$ and $y$ without adjusting for $x2$:

```
fit <- glm ( y ~  ns(x1,3) , df,family=binomial)
basis.vectors <- ns(df$x1,3)
projection <- basis.vectors %*% coef(fit)[2:4]
(g <- qplot(x = df$x1, projection) + geom_point())
```

[image]

In my application, the relationship between $y$ and $x1$ changes dramatically when I add in $x2$, but this example with iris is just to show the idea.

**Is it valid to interpret the first curve as the relationship between $x1$ and $y$ adjusted for $x2$?**

Comment: Yes, `ns(x1,3)` is simply a group of (linear) variables, as is `ns(x2,3)`. Thus, it is the relationship of one group of variables to $y$ conditioned on another group of variables.

Comment: If the outcome is boolean, why use linear regression or splines?

Comment: @user20160 I meant to say logistic regression.

Comment: @TimMak Okay, great, thanks. I just could not find any examples of papers where the authors presented these kinds of "conditional" plots using splines, so I wanted to check if this was the correct interpretation.